# Query without MAX function

Tags: sql, oracle, function, max

I need to do a query to obtain the employees with highest salaries without the MAX function.
I searched ways to do it and I found 'rownum' combined with 'order by' but to do this correctly we need to do a sub-query on the from clause, I can't do this because is prohibited by the teacher.

Someone knows the solution?

Thanks and excuse me for my English.

Comment: Isn't cheating by asking it on stack overflow ALSO prohibited by the teacher?

Comment: No matter whether this is your homework the minimal standards of asking a question on Stack Overflow apply. You've identified your problem, now what have you done to solve it? What is your query like, what is the sample data and the end result? Why isn't your query working and what error messages (if any) are you getting?

Comment: Sorry, but I've been testing queries during 2 hours without success. I'll ask this question directly to the teacher. Naomi, next time try to be more comprehensive.

Answer (score 2):

You could use some not-often-used SEMI-JOIN:

```
WHERE employee.salary >= ALL (...subquery...)
```

There are many other possibilities, for example with `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT deptno, e1.empno, e1.sal
  FROM scott.emp e1
 WHERE e1.sal >= ALL (SELECT e2.sal
                 FROM   scott.emp e2
                 WHERE  e2.deptno = 20 -- or e2.deptno = e1.deptno
                 )
 ORDER BY deptno
 /

DEPTNO  EMPNO   SAL
------------------------
10     7839    5000
20     7788    3000
20     7902    3000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select employee FROM 
   (Select * FROM tblEmployees ORDER BY Salary DESC)
       Where rownum = 1;
```

Returns the employee with the highest salary without using rank or max.

Comment: The question says a subquery in the from clause is prohibited too. I think. This solution already seems to have been rejected anyway.

Comment: I thought he was saying he needs to do a subquery because the max() function is prohibited. I guess we'll see.

Answer (score 0):

```
with emp_data as (
    select empno,
           sal,
           deptno,
           row_number() over (order by sal desc) as rn
    from emp
) 
select * 
from emp_data 
where rn = 1;
```

That's neither using `max()` nor using a sub-query in the `from` clause (although one could argue that using a common table expression is a way to cheat around the "no sub-query" requirement)